# which device is better for iphone development

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is it good idea to purchase Mac mini for iphone development. My friend suggested me that iMac with higher resolution is only good choice but it is very costly for me. If I compromise with Mac mini what will be disadvantages. Looking for your opinions.

Comment: whats the difference they both run xcode right

Comment: Any Mac that you're comfortable with, fits your budget, and runs the latest version of MacOS X and Xcode will be fine.

Comment: yes but as I mentioned my friend who is also an expert giving me advice for costlier iMac. I am conscious if anything wrong with mac-mini after purchase. He also was saying  it would be difficult to upgrade and may be speed performance issue with mini. Kindly give your suggestion.

Comment: i agree. there are no disadvatages except the time you have to wait for a build. But Screensize is a consideration, since xcode works particularly well on bigger screens.

Comment: @katzenhut, two standard monitors are even better and you can use dual.

Comment: @FeliceM - point taken.

Comment: please explain 'two standard monitors'. did you mean I can use different monitors with mac mini and it is better..?

Comment: @user2206911, I mean that you can connect two monitors to the macmini and would be better than a single one even if bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any recent Mac with an Intel processor will be able to run the current version of Xcode.
Four Gb of Ram are enough. Be careful with the monitor to check the interface. Keep in mind that you will also need an Apple developer subscription that is not for free. It should be around 100$ per year. Also consider that is not so difficult to resell a macmini if one day you wont to upgrade to something bigger and/or if you loose interest for coding.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I think I'll be OK with mac-mini.